# Extract information from HTML tag

Tags: jquery

I have this html code.

```
<a href="sample?ie=UTF8&amp;p=IDXYZ0123&amp;usecaseSessionID=64657491001" id="sample-link">TZX   (IDXYZ0123)</a>
```

I want to extract id "IDXYZ0123" from this. This id would be enclosed in `()` bracket.

Comment: Please invest more time into [doing your own research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418). If you *have* actually put some effort toward solving this problem, please include a [mcve] of what you've tried. Otherwise this question is just a work order, which is too broad, and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 1):

So you haven't tried anything so far and just want us to do the work for you?
Anyway, and just because it's so simple, here you go:

```js
console.log($('#sample-link').text().match(/\(([^]+)\)/)[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="sample?ie=UTF8&amp;p=IDXYZ0123&amp;usecaseSessionID=64657491001" id="sample-link">TZX   (IDXYZ0123)</a>
```

However, using jQuery is really overkill for this - it can be done with pure JS:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('sample-link').textContent.match(/\(([^]+)\)/)[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="sample?ie=UTF8&amp;p=IDXYZ0123&amp;usecaseSessionID=64657491001" id="sample-link">TZX   (IDXYZ0123)</a>
```

Comment: I have multiple entry with same id , Since JS getElementById returns only one entry, So using jquery $("[id]").each(function() .

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique. It's not valid to have multiple elements with the same ID. Use class names instead!

Comment: Yeah, I am writing the a greesmonkey script on a exiting website to extract some data. I don't own that. It's written like that only

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get it from the link text, rather than the href, and the ID will always be between brackets, you could do it like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var linkText = $('#sample-link').text(),
      start_pos = linkText.indexOf('(') + 1,
      end_pos = linkText.indexOf(')',start_pos),
      ID = linkText.substring(start_pos,end_pos);
      
  console.log('ID: ' + ID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="sample?ie=UTF8&amp;p=IDXYZ0123&amp;usecaseSessionID=64657491001" id="sample-link">TZX   (IDXYZ0123)</a>
```

Comment: They are called parentheses not brackets. Parentheses is (), brackets is [], braces is {}.

Comment: @Chloe [are you sure about that?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/168767) Regardless, I was simply using the same terminology as the OP.

Comment: @Chloe I believe it's also a matter of UK/US English or dialect at least. You can also call `[ ]` "square brackets" and `{ }` "curly brackets".

Comment: @Connum Yes I'm sure. It's a matter of mathematics, which is universal. The terms are very precise. Yes, you can colloquially use 'curly brackets' and people will know what you mean, but the correct terminology is 'brace'.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test_str=$('#sample-link').html();
test_str=test_str.substring(test_str.lastIndexOf("(")+1,test_str.lastIndexOf(")"));

console.log(test_str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="sample?ie=UTF8&amp;p=IDXYZ0123&amp;usecaseSessionID=64657491001" id="sample-link">TZX   (IDXYZ0123)</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To just get the id number using regex from txt2re.com:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var txt =  $("#sample-link").text();
    //from txt2re.com
    var re1='.*?'; // Non-greedy match on filler
    var re2='((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))'; // Alphanum 1

    var p = new RegExp(re1+re2,["i"]);
    var m = p.exec(txt);
    if (m !== null)
    {
        var id=m[1];
        $("#result").text(id);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <body>
    <a href="sample?ie=UTF8&amp;p=IDXYZ0123&amp;usecaseSessionID=64657491001" id="sample-link">TZX   (IDXYZ0123)</a>
    <div>
    <span>id:</span>
    <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
```